# Target a specific page template with Timber (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, timber

I am trying to output some HTML content on a specific page with a Timber file (.twig). I have been able to output content on the home page but not on a specific page.

I tried the following code :

```
% if fn (is_page('proprietes')) %}
    <h5 class="widget__headline">Test</h5>
    {% endif %}
```

But I end up with a blank page. I probably made a dump syntax mistake...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: is proprietes spelled correctly? are you missing the first { ?

Answer (score 2):

Correct way:

```
{% if fn('is_page', page) %}
```

"page" can be slug/id/array of id's etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using id instead of slug, eg:

```
{% if fn (is_page(7)) %}
    <h5 class="widget__headline">Test</h5>
{% endif %}
```